# NodeJS and Passport signup not working - no error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have published the current version on github: https://github.com/rcbgit/boiler

The user seems to be "logging in".  At least the successful redirect happens with valid username/pw and the failure redirect happens with a bad combo.  The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to store the user information after the login or validate a page against it (restrict access).  I created a basic 'Auth' service that stores the user information but i'm not sure how to use it properly.

I'm also having trouble figuring out how to handle messages back from the server such as "Username already exists!".

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) I assume the flash messages not showing up so well. I had issues with that too, so I reverted to using the session itself to pass the messages. Here is what I did instead that worked just fine:

I changed the req.flash to this:

```
req.session.signUpMessages.push('That email is already taken.');
```

then changed in my template to display this variable if it exists, works like a charm.

2) I think you can and should remove the  process.nextTick, it's great when you're doing authentication against external APIs that might take a long time, in this case it's more of an overkill IMO. I would remove it.

3) and last but not least, I think you're missing curley brackets..

```
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
    return done(err);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this get's called each time, that's not what you want...:)
```

should be turned to this:

```
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return done(err);
}
```

Try these changes, see if that solves the problems?

Comment: for some reason the entire middleware doesn't seem to executing.

I placed a console.log in the passport.use section of passport.js and it never hits. Also i removed nextTick.

everything compiles... no errors... just doesn't work.

Comment: @user1854837 can you please post your signup get route and template?

Comment: I created a github to post what I have so far.

https://github.com/rcbgit/boiler

As you can see i'm using angular-ui so i don't have any routes other than my post.

The problem now is that it seems to 'login' but I don't know how to access the user information in the session.  I created a service 'Auth' to store the user information and method to see if the user is logged in.  But I'm not sure how to set the service when passport has successfully logged in, or access it later... or verify its still valid.

Comment: @user1854837 glad to hear my helped solved your initial problem. can you please accept this as the answer and open a new question for the saving of the session? that is a different problem to the original questions. Also there are some redundancies in your git code there.

Comment: if you don't mind could you help me bout by pointing out those redundancies? don't leave me hanging! thanks man

Comment: @user1854837 - one that I saw quickly was adding the function on the singup / autenticaiton post, you can just use the autenticate right away, no need to have a function(req,res.etc). check the interface for that function. I have a few more things to do but will try to look at it more later on. Thanks!

Comment: really? I think i've confused myself on how passport is supposed to work.  I thought I HAD to make a post to authenticate.

Comment: I have simple auth working now. The github is current. if you wouldn't mind looking through it and giving me some notes about things that could be improved (specifically around the authentication) I would really appreciate it.